# Discord.js mention and user id array

Tags: discord.js

Was wondering how to add the message author id alongside the mention in an array. However, it gives back the error that message is not defined.

```
var user = ['<@' + message.author.id + '>', ` ${mention}`]
```

Comment: If you are trying to create `user` variable before `messageCreate` event fires - it will give you an error because message was **NOT** sent yet!

Comment: I'm not, it's way before the messagCreate event even happens.

Comment: @Bean that's exactly what they said

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that you're trying to access this outside of a messageCreate event. Use it inside the callback.